# comma vs && operator in loops and if-else

Tags: c, comma-operator

Consider the code:

```
if(x = a/b, a%b) 
 printf("do this");
else 
 printf("do that");
```

Now if I replace `if` statement by `if(x = a/b && a % b)`. Then it works also. So I want to know that replacing comma by `&&` operator and vice-versa works always or not in `if-else and loops`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are quite different!

---

In the first example, `,` is the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), which is a binary operator that evaluates its first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second operand and returns this value (and type).

So,

```
if(x = a/b, a%b)
```

is equivalent to (thanks to @jaket)

```
x = a/b;
if(a%b)
```

`a%b` will always be evaluated.

---

For the second one:

```
if(x = a/b && a % b)
```

is equivalent to

```
x = (a/b) && (a%b);
if( x )
```

`a%b` will only be evaluated if `a/b` (i.e. `a/b` is not zero) is true.

Comment: equivalent except for the side effect that x is assigned a value.

Comment: Ok, what about this `while(scanf("%d", &n), n)` and `while(scanf("%d", &n) && n)`;

Comment: @ashish2expert They will generate same result for this case. But I don't recommend you to write code like this. Consider readability.

Comment: That's why I confused.

Comment: @herohuyongtao Correct the mistake, if comma operator is used then both are evaluated while in and operator last one is evaluated only if first one is true.

Comment: @ashish2expert Yes, but your example is a little more complex than that as it involves assignment too. :P

Comment: @herohuyongtao, take this `int n = 0, cnt = 0; if(n, ++cnt) {printf("%d", cnt); `

Comment: @ashish2expert Yes, I get your idea. But there is no point for `n,` here. Right?

Answer (score 2):

if you replace the comma operator by &&, you're changing the logic slightly. What the comma operator does is it will execute x = a/b and "discard the result", i.e. it's not taken into consideration for the if's condition, only a%b is taken into account.

if you do

```
if(x = a/b && a % b)
```

then "do this" will be printed if and only if a/b is non zero and a % b is non zero. Whereas with the comma operator, "do this" is printed only if a % b is non zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(x = a/b, a%b)
```

is an obfuscated, unreadable way of writing

```
x = a/b;
if(a%b)
```

But

```
x = a/b && a % b
```

is equivalent to

```
x = ( (a/b) && (a%b) );
```

To sum it up, don't mix a whole lot of different operators on the same line. The *only* thing you achieved with it was to confuse yourself, while creating bugs.

Answer (score 0):

The && operator forces the the result of `a/b` as well into consideration in determining the expression `x = a/b && a%b`, In case of `,`, the result of `a/b` is ignored. So replacing `,` with `&&` will not work always. And not the right thing to do,